# что значит эта запись binding'a xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

что означает запись вида "@[LeftIcon:Enum:Symbol.Favorite]" в следующем коде:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="EmailsItemTemplate" x:DataType="data:Item">
        <controls:SlidableListItem 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                LeftIcon="@[LeftIcon:Enum:Symbol.Favorite]" 
                LeftCommand="{x:Bind ToggleFavorite}"
                RightCommand="{Binding DeleteItem, ElementName=Page, Mode=OneWay}"
                RightCommandParameter="{Binding}">
            <Grid Height="110" Background="Gray">
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind IsFavorite, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                               Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </controls:SlidableListItem>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Хм, никогда не видел такой синтаксис. А откуда ваш код?

Comment: из набора МС UWP Toolkit. Смотрел юзерконтроллы, и там был файл nameOfControll.xaml.bind, в котором было всё то же самое, что и в обычном nameOfControll.xaml, только вот с такими интересными записями.

Comment: @Arthur А где вы в UWP Community Toolkit такой файл нашли? Я не могу найти.

Comment: в папке контролс был, но сейчас что-то тоже найти не могу.  вот похожий, но не от туда. 
[ссылка](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/DropShadowPanel/DropShadowPanelXaml.bind)

Comment: @Arthur: Ага, там оно в файлах с расширением `.bind`. Попробую поискать что-то про это. К сожалению, `bind extension` плохо гуглится, приводит на `{x:Bind}`.

Comment: @VladD напишите статью на хабр про это, интересно почитать, что за зверь.

Comment: @MakeMakeluv: У меня нет инвайта на Хабр, каюсь :)

Comment: @VladD дык в песочницу, кто-нибудь да даст. Только сюда тоже ссылку пришлите, хочу в первых рядах почитать)